# IndexError: list index out of range python ( Print )

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was  trying to run this:

```
import sys

# Program 
print("Hallo",sys.argv[1])
```

But getting this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\Shakh\Desktop\Hello3.py", line 4, in 
> print("Hallo",sys.argv[1])
> IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Did you pass a command line argument?

Comment: Are you sure you're looking for `sys.argv`?

Comment: yeah. It's sample code was given but can't run it . That's why I asked.

Comment: @U8-Forward It could be but I found that before but looking chaos and difficult to understand. Thanks

Comment: How about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121717/list-index-out-of-range-when-using-sys-argv1

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31689100/sys-argv1-indexerror-list-index-out-of-range?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @U8-Forward ohh okay .. The last one was helpful. Thanks...

Comment: @StephenRauch No

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import sys
print("Hallo",sys.argv[0])
```

There is no index 1 at the time, list's index start with 0.

Answer (score 1):

sys.argv contains a list of command line arguments that you have supplied.

If you don't give any arguments (except for *python program.py*), the list will have only one argiment i.e., only sys.argv[0].

You will need to either give some argument like *python program.py xyz*, or use sys.argv[0]. Using sys.argv[0] will return the name of python file to you.

Comment: Can you explain how should I give some argument like (python program.py) . What you have written in your 3rd part 1st line .

Comment: If I wanted my program to say "Hello Vaibhav", then I would give the argument like python program.py Vaibhav.
And my print statement will be
print("Hello",sys.argv[1])

Answer (score 0):

`sys.argv` will hold command line arguments that you pass when you run the program. For example, you could run this as:

```
python Hello3.py Shakhawat
```

Comment: This would print HalloShakhawat as Hello3.py is the first element of sys.argv