# List Index out of range in sys.argv[1]?

Tags: python

Here is the code:

```
import cv2
import sys

cascPath = sys.argv[1]
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

and this is where the error pops up:

```
cascPath = sys.argv[1]
```

I don't know if the error is because I have not started a list although when I did start a list nothing happened and the error was still there

(this is not all the code as stack overflow did not allow me although I think this should be enough)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["list index out of range" when using sys.argv\[1\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121717/list-index-out-of-range-when-using-sys-argv1)

Comment: Read the documentation for `sys.argv` https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html?highlight=sys.argv#sys.argv -always a good idea to read the documentation.